# Vite keeps generating a 404.html file

Tags: vite

I've got a simple Vite project. Building it generates a `dist/404.html` file:

[image]

This is the default Firebase 404 page, as far as I can tell. (The project does use Firebase for auth.) That said, why is it generating it here, at build time? Or better yet: how can I stop it from doing it.